# Is "HaGevurah" really a name of God?

Tags: rambam, shemos-sacred-names, mishna

I am translating the "Thirteen Foundations of the Torah" (י"ג יסודות תורתנו) from the Qafih ("Kapach") edition of the Rambam's *Pirush HaMishnayot*. As usual, I run into philosophical difficulties with foundation #8 regarding the text of the Torah as we possess it. However, I noticed something that I possibly have been taking for granted: the Rambam says that "all of it is from the mouth of HaGevurah" (שהיא כולה מפי הגבורה), and then he explains himself by saying "That is to say, 'all of it came to him from HaShem Yitborakh.'" (כלומר: שהגיעה אליו כולה מאת ה' יתברך). It seems to me that if "ha-gevurah" was simply a designation for God himself, then it would be unecessary for him to explain. Now, I understand that [at least] part of his explanation has to do with what he says immediately afterward, i.e. that the entire concept of "speech" or "speaking" when applied to God is merely metaphorical, but there appears to be more here beside this. [NOTE: I am also aware that "*ha-gevurah*" comes from *b.Makkot* 23b, and similar passages.]

So, my questions are:

1. Is "*ha-gevurah*" simply an appelation for God, or does it imply something else in rabbinic usage?
2. Why does Rambam specifically use it here in this context? Does it have a technical meaning that fits the context of the Torah's origins/transmission?

Please cite your sources! Thanks.

Comment: See the entry גבורה in Jastrow's dictionary, second meaning, "Divine Majesty, the Lord", and some places it's used, like Shabbat 87a and 88b.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does "הגבורה" also appear in Judeo-Arabic original?